# Need jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following snippet of code on a page that I need to specifically target the number inside the b tag and put that number in a variable. I do not have direct access to this code or I would put and ID there. There are more than one td and b tags on the page but only one font size"3". What would be the correct selector to target this text?

```
<td><font size="3"><b>3947</b></font></td>
```

This is the code I have so far but it returns other bold text on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var invoice_number = $("td b").text();
alert(invoice_number);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var invoice_number = $("td font[size='3'] b").text();
  alert(invoice_number);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2ghtB/).

Comment: lol i had it backwards I tried this but didn't work var invoice_number = $("td b font[size=3]").text();

Comment: @user357034 - welcome :) - If you have control over it, I'd look at changing the markup, giving the cell itself a class, less markup and an easier selector :)

Comment: I wish I did but unfortunately no I have no access to the markup

Comment: @user357034 - I figured that was the case given the `<font>` tag in the first place, oh well, sorry!